# What's the simplest way to convert from a single character String to an ASCII value in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, character, ascii

I just want to get the ASCII value of a single char string in Swift. This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
var singleChar = "a"
println(singleChar.unicodeScalars[singleChar.unicodeScalars.startIndex].value) //prints: 97
```

This is so ugly though. There must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

**edit/update Swift 5.2 or later**

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var asciiValues: [UInt8] { compactMap(\.asciiValue) }
}
```

---

```
"abc".asciiValues  // [97, 98, 99]
```

---

In Swift 5 you can use the new character properties [isASCII](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127007-isascii) and [asciiValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127002-asciivalue)

```
Character("a").isASCII       // true
Character("a").asciiValue    // 97

Character("á").isASCII       // false
Character("á").asciiValue    // nil
```

---

Old answer

You can create an extension:

**Swift 4.2 or later**

```
extension Character {
    var isAscii: Bool {
        return unicodeScalars.allSatisfy { $0.isASCII }
    }
    var ascii: UInt32? {
        return isAscii ? unicodeScalars.first?.value : nil
    }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var asciiValues: [UInt32] {
        return compactMap { $0.ascii }
    }
}
```

---

```
Character("a").isAscii  // true
Character("a").ascii    // 97

Character("á").isAscii  // false
Character("á").ascii    // nil

"abc".asciiValues            // [97, 98, 99]
"abc".asciiValues[0]         // 97
"abc".asciiValues[1]         // 98
"abc".asciiValues[2]         // 99
```

Answer (score 15):

```
UnicodeScalar("1")!.value // returns 49
```

Swift 3.1

Comment: @ixany forced unwraps exist for a reason, plus in this case we're 101% sure the initializer won't fail ("1" is a valid character).

Comment: @Cristik Disagree. In general, you can’t be sure that an input value won’t fail forever. So why not playing it safe? Better approach would be: `guard let value = UnicodeScalar("1")?.value else { return }`.

Comment: @ixany, you disagree that "1" is a valid character? :)

Comment: @Cristik `if let` or `guard let` statements too exist for a reason. I’m convinced that, whenever possible, you should play things safe. And that we, as more experienced developer, should provide good coding style and best practices for all the newcomers here at stackoverflow. It was not meant as an offence.

Comment: @ixany, yes, agreed, and myself avoid forced unwraps as much as possible, however there are (rare or very rare) cases when forced unwraps make sense. Your "never a good idea" seemed a little bit drastic to me in the answer context, that's why I replied :)

Answer (score 11):

Now in Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2.1

```swing
var singleChar = "a"

singleChar.unicodeScalars.first?.value
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use NSString's [characterAtIndex](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex:) to accomplish this...

```
var singleCharString = "a" as NSString
var singleCharValue = singleCharString.characterAtIndex(0)
println("The value of \(singleCharString) is \(singleCharValue)")  // The value of a is 97
```

Comment: @vacawama Swift 4, I am getting error `error: value of type 'String' has no member 'character'`. but when using "a" as NSString its working :)

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4.2**

The easiest way to get ASCII values from a Swift string is below

```
let str = "Swift string"
for ascii in str.utf8 {
    print(ascii)
}
```

Output:

```
83
119
105
102
116
32
115
116
114
105
110
103
```

Comment: This is not the ascii values. This will return an array of bytes. A character other than ascii will return multiple bytes with no relation with the ascii table.

Comment: try `let str = ""`
`for ascii in str.utf8 {`
    `print(ascii)`
`}` // 240, 159, 152, 128`

Answer (score 3):

The way you're doing it is right. If you don't like the verbosity of the indexing, you can avoid it by cycling through the unicode scalars:

```
var x : UInt32 = 0
let char = "a"
for sc in char.unicodeScalars {x = sc.value; break}
```

You can actually omit the `break` in this case, of course, since there is only one unicode scalar.

Or, convert to an Array and use Int indexing (the last resort of the desperate):

```
let char = "a"
let x = Array(char.unicodeScalars)[0].value
```

Answer (score 3):

A slightly shorter way of doing this could be:

```
first(singleChar.unicodeScalars)!.value
```

As with the subscript version, this will crash if your string is actually empty, so if you’re not 100% sure, use the optional:

```
if let ascii = first(singleChar.unicodeScalars)?.value {

}
```

Or, if you want to be extra-paranoid,

```
if let char = first(singleChar.unicodeScalars) where char.isASCII() {
    let ascii = char.value
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my implementation, it returns an array of the ASCII values.

```
extension String {

    func asciiValueOfString() -> [UInt32] {

      var retVal = [UInt32]()
      for val in self.unicodeScalars where val.isASCII() {
          retVal.append(UInt32(val))
      }
      return retVal
    }
}
```

Note: Yes it's Swift 2 compatible.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.1**

https://oleb.net/blog/2017/11/swift-4-strings/

```
let flags = "99_problems"
flags.unicodeScalars.map {
    "\(String($0.value, radix: 16, uppercase: true))"
}
```

Result:

`["39", "39", "5F", "70", "72", "6F", "62", "6C", "65", "6D", "73"]`

Comment: try `let flags = ""`
`flags.unicodeScalars.map {`
    `"\(String($0.value, radix: 16, uppercase: true))"` 
`}`  // "1F600"

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4+

Char to ASCII

```
let charVal = String(ch).unicodeScalars
var asciiVal = charVal[charVal.startIndex].value
```

ASCII to Char

```
let char = Character(UnicodeScalar(asciiVal)!)
```

Comment: try `let charVal = String("").unicodeScalars`
`charVal[charVal.startIndex].value` // 128512

Answer (score 1):

```
var singchar = "a" as NSString

print(singchar.character(at: 0))
```

Swift 3.1

Answer (score 1):

There's also the UInt8(ascii: Unicode.Scalar) initializer on UInt8.

```
var singleChar = "a"
UInt8(ascii: singleChar.unicodeScalars[singleChar.startIndex])
```

Comment: Note that this is a non fallible initialiser. It will crash if you pass an invalid character which its value is out of the ascii range 0..<128. **"Fatal error: Code point value does not fit into ASCII"**

Comment: try `var singleChar = ""`
`UInt8(ascii: singleChar.unicodeScalars[singleChar.startIndex])` // Fatal error: Code point value does not fit into ASCII: file /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1200.2.10.322/swift/stdlib/public/core/UnicodeScalar.swift, line 354`

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 5, you can pick one of the following approaches in order to get the ASCII numeric representation of a character.

---

### #1. Using `Character`'s `asciiValue` property

`Character` has a property called [`asciiValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127002-asciivalue). `asciiValue` has the following declaration:

```
var asciiValue: UInt8? { get }
```

> The ASCII encoding value of this character, if it is an ASCII character.

The following Playground sample codes show how to use `asciiValue` in order to get 
the ASCII encoding value of a character:

```
let character: Character = "a"
print(character.asciiValue) //prints: Optional(97)
```

```
let string = "a"
print(string.first?.asciiValue) //prints: Optional(97)
```

```
let character: Character = ""
print(character.asciiValue) //prints: nil
```

---

### #2. Using `Character`'s `isASCII` property and `Unicode.Scalar`'s `value` property

As an alternative, you can check that the first character of a string is an ASCII character (using `Character`'s [`isASCII`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127007-isascii) property) then get the numeric representation of its first Unicode scalar (using `Unicode.Scalar`'s [`value`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/2908540-value) property). The Playground sample code below show how to proceed:

```
let character: Character = "a"
if character.isASCII, let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first {
    print(scalar.value)
} else {
    print("Not an ASCII character")
}
/*
 prints: 97
 */
```

```
let string = "a"
if let character = string.first, character.isASCII, let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first {
    print(scalar.value)
} else {
    print("Not an ASCII character")
}
/*
 prints: 97
 */
```

```
let character: Character = ""
if character.isASCII, let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first {
    print(scalar.value)
} else {
    print("Not an ASCII character")
}
/*
 prints: Not an ASCII character
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
print("c".utf8["c".utf8.startIndex])
```

or

```
let cu = "c".utf8
print(cu[cu.startIndex])
```

Both print 99. Works for any ASCII character.

Answer (score 0):

var input = "Swift".map {
Character(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral: $0).asciiValue!
}

// [83, 119, 105, 102, 116]