# Trying to obtain ASCII value of individual characters found in String using Swift

Tags: swift, string, char

I'm trying to figure out how to obtain the numeric value of characters that are contained in a String object.

e.g.

```
let checkString = "ball"
for i in checkString.characters {
    var val = Int(String(i))!
    print(val)
}
```

I would like my output to be:

```
ASCII value of 'b'
ASCII value of 'a'
ASCII value of 'l'
ASCII value of 'l'
```

However, I get instead the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

In Java, the equivalent code is:

```
int val = str.charAt(i)
```

Can anyone see where it is I'm going wrong?

Comment: So you want `a` to be treated as 1 and `z` as 26. How do you want to handle the many thousands of other possible characters that might be in a string?

Comment: BTW - read the documentation for `Int?(String)` to see why your code is crashing.

Comment: @rmaddy Ideally, yes.  However, is it possible for me to obtain the ascii value instead which is what the java code returns?

Comment: ASCII only covers a tiny portion of the possible Unicode values you can have in a string.

Comment: @syedfa If you want the ASCII value then ask for that in your question instead of asking to get 1 for `a`, etc.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks very much for clarifying.  I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: Since you really want the ASCII value we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @rmaddy Agreed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post [What's the simplest way to convert from a single character String to an ASCII value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835242/whats-the-simplest-way-to-convert-from-a-single-character-string-to-an-ascii-va?answertab=active#tab-top) you could try this:

```
extension String {
    var asciiArray: [UInt32] {
        return unicodeScalars.filter{$0.isASCII}.map{$0.value}
    }
}

extension Character {
    var asciiValue: UInt32? {
        return     String(self).unicodeScalars.filter{$0.isASCII}.first?.value
    }
}

"ball".lowercased().asciiArray.forEach { print($0 - 96) }
```

Notice this will only work for *lowered case* string since the calculation is ASCII based, therefore 97 equals "a", 98 "b" and so on. If you want to adapt it to *upper case* strings you would need to use this line instead:

```
"UPpER".uppercased().asciiArray.forEach { print($0 - 64) }
```

Comment: Are you sure? I just tested your case in my playground and get 1 for both of them (`A` and `a`)

Comment: Did you test it @syedfa?