# How to convert the string into ASCII Values in array and add those elements in Swift?

Tags: swift

How to convert this string "RAHUL" into ASCII Values in array and adding all the elements of array.

```
var myString: String = "RAHUL"

for scalar in myString.unicodeScalars 
{
    print(scalar.value)
    var num = scalar.value
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to convert from a single character String to an ASCII value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835242/whats-the-simplest-way-to-convert-from-a-single-character-string-to-an-ascii-va)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
var myString = "RAHUL"
let asciiValues = myString.compactMap { $0.asciiValue }
print(asciiValues) // [82, 65, 72, 85, 76]
```

If you want to add the values

```
let sum = asciiValues.reduce(0, { Int($0) + Int($1) })
print(sum) // 380
```

Answer (score 2):

Just convert the `num` to a `Int` and add them to an array:

```
var myString: String = "RAHUL"
var asciiArray = [Int]()

for scalar in myString.unicodeScalars 
{
    var num = Int(scalar.value)
    asciiArray.append(num)
}

print(asciiArray)    //Prints [82, 65, 72, 85, 76]
```