# What is an elegant way of constructing a character from int, and int to character?

Tags: ios, swift

What is an elegant way of converting a character from int, and int to character?

for example, for an often operation of a -> 0, how do i convert this in swift? And how do i convert 0 -> a?

Currently i use unicode to achieve what i want..

```
let int = char.unicodeScalars.first!.value - 65
```

65 is the uniscalar code number of "A", But i find this really verbose.

Anyone knows a better way of dealing with this kind of stuff in swift?

Comment: Not clear what you're after here. Are you asking how to get the ascii value of a character and vice versa?

Comment: @keno yes, i mean. I know how to, just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: What would the expected result be for an emoji "" or a flag ""  (which consists of multiple Unicode scalars)?

Comment: @MartinR This is more for algorithm purpose. For example, in a lot of algorithm problems, we need to store characters in an array of [Int]. 0 means "a". I have been using unicode.scalar to have a private convertion function most of time, but just wondering if there is a better approach

Comment: Check this SO answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835242/whats-the-simplest-way-to-convert-from-a-single-character-string-to-an-ascii-va

Apparently there are some new properties in Swift 5 that can help.